# what have made rake faster in rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rake

For last few months, I have been watching my rails3 and rails4 projects, and I found rake is faster in rails4, is that the case with you all?, any guesses as to what made it so? And can I make my rails3 rake faster by adding/removing a few lines of rails code?

I also found rails console gets launched faster in rails4.

Rather I am looking for what quick changes to do to your rails app making it load faster in general. What are your favourite ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This boost up provided with ruby 2.0. The performance grows from version to version.
In Ruby 2.0+ was improved Garbage collector algorithm.